# <noscripts /> escapes its own <iframe> content

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So, I can't figure out why any code inside `noscript`, like:

```
 <noscript>
     <iframe ...></iframe>
 </noscript>
```

... will be interpreted once insred by DOM like:

```
 <noscript>
     "<iframe ...></iframe>" // the <iframe /> is escaped and treated like text
 </noscript>
```

Does someone know why?

Comment: I did not understand you Can you explain more?

Answer (score 1):

All [`noscript`](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-html/html-noscript-tag.html) content is escaped when javascript is enabled. Try this with a `<strong>` tag and you'll see the same thing. However, when javascript is disabled, it works as expected.

Comment: I don't see anything on the page you linked to that says that

Comment: @j08691 changed to the w3docs reference: "The <noscript> tag has an alternative content, which is displayed in the browsers, that don’t support scripts, or the browsers, where the script support is disabled by the user. In other cases, _the browser ignores this tag and its content_."

Comment: Ignoring the content isn't the same as escaping it

Comment: True, but I think it's what the OP was talking about.  It is browser dependent on what "ignoring" means. Safari does in fact escape the text (`element.innerHtml` contains escape characters). Chrome does not change the characters. But in both cases, `element.innerText` contains text of what would otherwise be html content.